# Heywood Case in R for Exploratory Factor Analysis

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I am working with R to run an Exploratory Factor Analysis and got a warning that a Heywood case was detected using the following code in the psych package:

threefactor = fa(data, nfactors = 3, rotate = "oblimin", fm = "ml")

I'm looking at the output and I can't figure out how I find said Heywood case.  Any help is appreciated!

[Click for R Output Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASpJw.png)
[image]

Comment: It would be beneficial to provide some context; I for one don't know what an EFA is; nor do I know about Heywood cases. Not providing any information (or reproducible code for that matter), potentially requires respondents to spend a lot more time researching instead of helping...

Comment: It looks like you have communalities (`com`) larger than 1, and that is a Heywood case (see also https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/216103/27276). If you provide more context, your question may fit better on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!  I edited the post to clarify that EFA is Exploratory Factor Analysis and will add in the code I ran.
I also thought it might be the "com" column, but in the psych package, this column refers to complexity as opposed to communality.